# Maximal pruned subtree - an absolute notion?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Fix a tree $ p $ over $ \omega $. Let $ [p] $ denote the set of all branches of $ p $. Given a set of reals $ F \subseteq \omega^\omega $, let $ T(F) := \{ x \mathord{\upharpoonright} n : x \in F \land n < \omega \} $. Clearly, $ T([p]) \subseteq p $ is a maximal pruned subtree of $ p $.

But $ p \mapsto [p] $ is not absolute for transitive models of ZF. So can we construct a maximal pruned subtree in an absolute way?

My idea: Let $ \mathbf{M} $ be a transitive model for ZF. Suppose $ p \in \mathbf{M} $. Now define $ \langle q_n : n < \omega \rangle $ recursively (within $ \mathbf{M} $) by $ q_0 = p $ and $ q_{n + 1} = q_n \setminus \{ s \in q_n : s \text{ is a terminal node of } q_n \} $ for all $ n < \omega $. Let $ p^* := \bigcap \{ q_n : n < \omega \} $. ($ p \mapsto p^* $ should be absolute.)

Does $ \bigl( p^* = T([p]) \bigr)^\mathbf{M} $ hold? And what about $ p^* = T([p]) $ (in $ \mathbf{V} $)?

Comment: You should amend your definition of $p^{\star}$ by iterating the process of removing terminal nodes $\omega_1$ many times. One way of looking at $p^{\star}$ is that there is a rank function $r: p \rightarrow \omega_1 \bigcup \{\infty\}$ for any subtree $p \subseteq \omega^{<\omega}$ and then the maximal pruned subtree $p^{\star}$ will consist of nodes whose ranks are $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, one should know about the rank function and the well-founded part of a tree. This is covered in *Alexander Kechris*'s book *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* in sections I.2.E and I.2.F for example.

Kechris defines
$$
\operatorname{WF}_T := \{ s \in T : T_s \text{ is well-founded}\}.
$$
for each tree $ T \subseteq A^{<\omega} $.

(Here $ T_s := \{t \in A^{<\omega} : s^\smallfrown t \in T \} $ for each $ s \in T $.)

One easily sees that $ T^* := T \setminus \operatorname{WF}_T $ is the maximal pruned subtree. This is exactly the set of nodes whose ranks are $ \infty := (\max \{ |A|, \aleph_0 \})^+ $.

Remark that "$ R \text{ is a well-founded relation on } A $" is absolute for transitive models of $ \mathrm{ZF} - \mathrm{P} $ ($ \mathrm{ZF} $ without the power set axiom).

So the definition of $ \operatorname{WF}_T $ (and hence of $ T^* $) is also absolute for transitive models of $ \mathrm{ZF} - \mathrm{P} $.

Comment: This answer is based on hot_queen's comment above. Thanks!